# How to show prompt on navigation (GatsbyJS/ReachRouter)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

Is it possible to show a page confirm before navigating away from a page? I'm currently using `GatsbyJS/@reach-router`. All the posts I see is how easy it is to do it in `react-router` but I have never seen an implementation in the framework I'm currently using.

The reason why I needed this implemented is that I wanted to compare the first state on the page's first load and what had been done to this particular state (if the user had put some inputs to it). Basically, I'm using Redux as my state (as there are a lot of components and I didn't want to keep passing props from great grandparent components downward and below - it'll be quite messy).

So, I just wanted to throw a confirm/modal in case they had made some changes and they had mistakenly navigated (so we can save the data...). How do we implement this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

can try this?

```
import { useLocation, globalHistory, useNavigate } from "@reach/router";

const curLocation = useLocation();
const navigate = useNavigate();

useEffect(() => {
  return globalHistory.listen(({ action, location }) => {
    if (
      (action === "PUSH" && !location.pathname.includes("/verify/")) ||
      action === "POP"
    ) {
      if (!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to exit video screening?")) {
        navigate(`${curLocation.pathname}`);
      }
    }
  });
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to prevent the user to navigate off of your page you can listen to the [beforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) and call `preventDefault()` on the event. This is not specific to reach-router or gatsby.

If you want to prevent accidental navigation interal to your page you could use the onClick-prop of reach-router's [Link-component](https://reach.tech/router/api/Link). There you could trigger the comparison of the states and do the saving. In case you wanted to stop the navigation you could also call `preventDefault` on the event.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn’t work, I think it has something to do with how @reach/router is architected, even after adding this to componentDidMount, nothing gets fired at all (not even a console.log in the callback of that addEventListener). I gave up actually, I’m doing a YAGNI on it temporarily haha.